# How to Refresh the tabs page using view pager in Fragements

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have two tabs in my fragment using viewpager. I have API rest calls in both tab when i go to tab 2(Clocking) and click tab 1(Dashboard) i want to refresh the tab 1 i want to call the API rest call again ,but its not refreshing.please help me.
This is my view pager code:

```
public class TabSampleFragment extends Fragment {
    TabLayout gs_tabLayout;
    ViewPager gs_viewPager;
    ViewPagerAdapter mViewPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {    

        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_frag_tabs, container, false);
        gs_tabLayout = (TabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.gs_tabLayout);
        gs_viewPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.gs_viewPager);
        mViewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        mViewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new Progress(), "Dashboard");
        mViewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new ClockInDetails(), "Clocking");
        gs_viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }  @Override
              public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                     mViewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //this line will force all pages to be loaded fresh when changing between fragments
                                          }   
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) { 
            }
        });
        gs_viewPager.setAdapter(mViewPagerAdapter);
        gs_tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(gs_viewPager);
        gs_tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        mViewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return view;
    }    
}
```

This is my adapter code:How to refresh the dashboard tab when i click,the fragments lifecycle also not calling(onstart,onpause,onresume,onstop when clicking tabs)

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
  ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> tabTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addFragments(Fragment fragments, String titles){
        Log.i("RR","on add-gragment");
        this.fragments.add(fragments);
        this.tabTitles.add(titles);
    }

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }    
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);

    }    
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }    
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabTitles.get(position);
    }

}
```

This is my dashboard code.I am calling REST API using string request in oncreate and uservisiblehint method.if i did not call rest call in uservisiblehint method its working but if i call means its showing issue

```
enter code here
public class Progress extends Fragment {
    ProgressBar gs_circularProgressBar;
    public ProgressDialog mProgDialog;
    ImageView gs_image_userProfileimage;
    private TextView gs_text_username, gs_text_companyname, gs_text_completedTaskasValue,  gs_text_assignedTaskasValue, gs_assignedTaskTextView, gs_text_totalDistanceValue, gs_totalDistanceTextView, gs_kmsLabel, gs_totalHoursTextView, gs_text_totalHoursasValue;
    Typeface tf1, tf2, tf3, tf4;
    Float gs_var_dist_travel;
    String gs_var_userimage,gs_var_username,gs_var_companyname,gs_var_total_task,gs_var_complete_task,gs_var_timetaken,gs_var_roleid,gs_var_userid;
    int gs_var_networkx=2;
    public Progress() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

ProgressBar progressBar1;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.con_fragment_progress, container, false);
        gs_circularProgressBar = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById (R.id.gs_circularProgressBar);
        GS_User_Dashboard(gs_var_roleid,gs_var_userid);

        return view;
    }



    private void GS_User_Dashboard( String gs_var_roleid, String gs_var_userid) {
       StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, ServerUtils.Gs_User_Dashboard+"gs_userId="+gs_var_userid+"&gs_role="+gs_var_roleid,
                new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                    }
                },
                new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        //Dismissing the progress dialog
                        clearProgressDialog();
                        progressBar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        //Showing toast
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();
                return params;
            }
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                return params;
            }

            @Override protected void deliverResponse(String response) {
                super.deliverResponse(response);
            }
            @Override public void deliverError(VolleyError error)
            {
                super.deliverError(error);
              //  progressBar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Log.e("deliverResponse", "getNetworkTimeMs : " + error);
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            // load data here and api call
        GS_User_Dashboard(gs_var_roleid,gs_var_userid);
         Log.i("EE","visible--progress");
        }else{

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please Anyone help me to fix the above problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> View pager will by default load atleast 1 on the right and one on the left tab of current tab. It is done so, mostly because there is a point when u slide viewpager, when certain area of both tabs is visible. For those smooth transitions preloading is required.

But since you only have two tab this was a problem,both tab are preloaded and not refresh when you go to second tab.

I suggest you to Override `setUserVisibleHint()` method and do the api call there.

Try below code:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
 super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
 if (isVisibleToUser) {
   // load data here and api call
 }else{

 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution.I put this method and i print one Log its working when i click tabs.But i ahve to call the API rest call i given like this

Comment: but its showing an issue when i am passing getcontext() in fragment. "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getCacheDir()' on a null object reference".Please help me

Comment: Am using String Request API so i need to pass the content in Request queue,but its showing error

Comment: RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

Comment: Please Help me @Abhishek

Comment: Where are you calling API inside fragment or in Activity ? @kalaivani

Comment: Yes am using fragment.

Comment: //Creating a Request Queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);--see context i need to pass context if i pass its showing issue

Comment: @kalai vani I observer that you are asking question and got correct answers but not accepting it. In this way may community stop helping you.

Comment: normal that restcall working but when am using ur method"uservisiblehint" that time only its shwoing issue

Comment: @Abhishekkumar.I accepted your answer,my internet is slow thats why late.

Comment: Or ASk new question.

Comment: I added my dashboard API fragment pls check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165276/discussion-between--and-kalai-vani).